# able to send simple mail but unable to send my html view file in sending mail code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer, codeigniter-3

i am able to send mail but now  i am trying to send mail in a proper way that it will look good to recwiver so i want to attach a html view file for its looks  html file is sended also but i am not able to send proper data in it as it is not changing dynamically its showing statis values .

here's my controlller code .....

```
  public function forgetuser()
    {
        $Uid = $this->input->post('uid');
      

        
        $otp = rand(10,1000000);

        $mail =  $dat = $this->Lib_model->Select('ur_super_users', '*', array('isActive'=> 1,'id' => $Uid));

$receiverMail = $mail[0]->emailId;
       $count = 0 ;



       if ($count == 0) {
           
           $f = array(
               'otp' => $otp,
               
               

           );

           $this->Lib_model->Update('ur_super_users', $f, array('id' => $Uid));
           //$this->Lib_model->Insert('ur_super_users', $f);
           
//mailer request
$data = Forget_Mail ($receiverMail, $Uid,$otp,$dat);
          

 if (!empty($insert_users)) {
            $Msg = array('Msg' => 'Assigned Successfully', 'Type' => 'success');
            $this->session->set_flashdata($Msg);
            redirect(base_url('/frontend/homepage/forget'));
        }
```

my e mail helper function----

```
if (!function_exists('Forget_Mail')) {

    function Forget_Mail($email, $Uid, $otp,$dat)
    {
        $otp = $otp;
        $Uid = $Uid ;
        $to_email = $email;


        $link = 'http://www.abcd.com/frontend/homepage/forgetpwd/'.$Uid.'/'.$otp.'';

        $BaseUrl = '"<?php echo base_url() ?>"'; 

        $from_email = 'info@abcd.com';

        
        $user = array('Uid' =>  $Uid , 'otp' => $otp);
        //$from_name = 'abcd';
        $from_name = 'abcd';

        $config = array(

            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'xyz@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'xyz@1236',
            'mailtype'  => 'html',
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
        );
        $CI = &get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('email', $config);
        $CI->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $CI->email->from($from_email, $from_name);
        $CI->email->to($to_email);  // replace it with receiver mail id
        $CI->email->subject('Forget Password Link |'  . $from_name); // replace it with relevant subject

//request for html view page to in mail it is loading but not sending varible array value

        $body = $CI->load->view('email_templates/forget', $user, TRUE);
       
       
       
         $CI->email->message($body);
        //Send mail 
        if ($CI->email->send()){
            //prx($link);
            
        redirect(base_url('/frontend/homepage/forget'));
        
       // return true;
         } else{return true;
          // return false;}
         }
    }
}
```

my view html file  forget.php

```
 <br>
    Click here to Reset Your Password : <b><a href="http://abcd.com/frontend/homepage/forgetpwd/'.$Uid.'/'.$otp.' ">

//this is coming same in received mail not changing with each user 
         
         Reset Password</a></b>

    <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Use the Template Parser Class  in Codeigniter.`
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/parser.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are not printing/echo the variables to the html code. (Assuming that a portion of forget.php code is provided). You could try either of the below:

- Change views to

```
<br>
    Click here to Reset Your Password : <b><a href="http://abcd.com/frontend/homepage/forgetpwd/<?= $Uid; ?>/<?= $otp; ?>">
     
   Reset Password</a></b>

<br>
```

OR

- you could use the [CI parser library](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/parser.html)

```
$CI->load->library('parser');
$user = array(
        'Uid' => $Uid , 
        'otp' => $otp
);

$body = $CI->parser->parse('email_templates/forget', $user, TRUE);

**

$CI->email->message($body);

**
```

and change your forget.php to

```
<br>
    Click here to Reset Your Password : <b><a href="http://abcd.com/frontend/homepage/forgetpwd/{Uid}/{otp}">

//this is coming same in received mail not changing with each user 
         
   Reset Password</a></b>

<br>
```

Comment: @animeshsoni Welcome to SO. Please read this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: actully i can't vote it now as i'm not having priviledges

Comment: but i appreciate your answer thnx again